# Install a windows phone app from uri

Tags: windows-phone-8, windows-phone-8.1

I make program to download a windows phone app and store on storage.now i want to install this app after download finish automatically like windows phone store application.how can i do this?

Answer (score 3):

You cannot. Windows Phone devices are locked and only allow installing applications from the official Microsoft store, unless you are a developer and unlock your own phone.

Even if you managed to do it on an unlocked phone you would never be approved on the official store.

Comment: Even an unlocked device refuses to install apps without the USB cable.. another reason for the failure of this OS.